# How can i make transection using .where

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Since transaction only accepts `DocumentReference` so I couldn't handle the .where().

```
 DocumentReference test1=  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid);

Query<Map<String, dynamic>> test2=   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").where('test',isEqualTo: 'mytest').limit(1);

    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {

      //no problem with this DocumentSnapshot 
      DocumentSnapshot _value = await transaction.get(test1);
     

      //BUT
      //here in test2 will never accept Query<Map<String, dynamic>>
      //since the transaction is only accept DocumentReference 
      DocumentSnapshot _value2 = await transaction.get(test2);

      if (_value.exists) {
     //action
      }

    })
```

How can I get the `.where`Reference into the transaction?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no :/

Comment: So you need to use a transaction for multiple documents, right?

Comment: No , only one document .limit(1) using .where() , since the document depends on user input for field value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Firestore doesn't provide a solution in which you can use transactions on documents that are obtained through queries. Please also note that a Transaction object cannot perform a query. The single option that you have is to use transactions on a single individual document.

According to your last comment, since you are using a `.limit(1)` it means that you need to update a single document, a case in which you can create a reference that points exactly to that document and perform the transaction:

```
DocumentReference uidRef =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid);
uidRef.runTransaction(/* ... /*);
```

If you don't know the UID of the user on which you need to perform the transaction, then you should perform the necessary query outside the transaction, get the ID of the document, and perform the transaction right after that. But as you can see, there is no way you can do these two operations in a single go.

Please also remember, that a transaction makes sense to be used only if you need to read some data from a document in order to make a decision before you update it. I'm not 100% sure, but in your particular case, I don't think you do that. You are not using the value of `_value` in a way you decide what to do with it.  If this is your scenario, a batch write will definitely do the job.

Comment: yes exactly i don't know the user uid , even i couldn't get it outside the transaction, because i don't know if it exist or not , however if i do it  so it might be null which transection will never perform it  basically i use it for race condition ! ,  and it is work prefect with single doc , race condition i mean creating docs depends on others existence , but not in case if UID was unknown and it might be not exist

Comment: , for example to sign up with name that not exist with other user , name as field value  , so after your answer imagine that i am going to do new collection just to hold all names as a doc uid and not field value so i can perform it in transection :/

Comment: note that the first doc reference (test1) in example its only for example its not wanted anymore

Comment: It doesn't matter if the user exists or not. If it does, then simply perform the transaction, and if doesn't then there is no action to take. And it makes sense not to perform a transaction if that particular user doesn't exist. There is no race condition in this case.

Comment: But the single option that you have is to find the desired document, get the ID and perform the transaction on that document.

Comment: if you mean with using .where so that was my question , else i couldn't do it out transection in my case

Comment: There is no way you can use transactions in a query. You should perform the query (**outside** the transaction), get the ID of the document, and right after that perform the transaction. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: i understand you as well and yes i tested it,  i get the an UID outside the transection and it is work because i tested it using UID that i already know it , but what if the UID was unknown  or if it was depends of user input  or if it needs .where , your idea is useful if UID was known

Comment: that's it .where not allow as what you said and thanks for telling me this ,